# Que and inversion

Tags: pronoms-relatifs, inversion

le jeu que jouait la classe

How can I explain this use of que to my French class?

I looked up inversion of pronom relatif but found no references to QUE. I figure that it is a slightly antiquated inverted structure that can be used stylistically.

Comment: I think your question was maybe a little too quickly marked as duplicate. Nevermind. "Le jeu que jouait la classe" is something completely different from " le jeu auquel la classe jouait" because "jouer un jeu" is very different from "jouer à un jeu". "jouer un jeu" means to act in such a way as to achieve a specific goal. It has absolute nothing to do with a game. I think the inversion comes from this difference.

Comment: @user45784: The inversion is always possible, both with *que* and *auquel*, as long as the subject of the relative clause is not a pronoun. Now if the question is really about the possibility of using *que* instead of *auquel* here, it could be reopened. But it doesn't seem to be the case.